# Method to not accept one of the child class type - Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a question related to inheritance and generics in java.
I have a below class

```
class Employee{
//Id
//Name
//Salary
}

class Developer extends Employee{
}

class Manager extends Employee{
}

class Director extends Employee{
}
```

In one of the implementation i have a method to print the details of the employee,

```
 public method printEmployee(Employee e){
// print the details.
}
```

To allow all Employee types i can modify the method like,

```
public method printEmployee(? extends Employee e){
// print the details.
}
```

But is there a way i can restrict the method to allow only Developer and Managers or Managers and Directors.

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: You can create a private method that takes `Employee`, then expose two overloaded methods taking `Developer` and `Manager`, and call the private method from those. You can't solve that using generics.

Comment: "to allow all Employee types", you don't need to add ? extends Employee. Developer,  Manager and Director will all pass an IS-A test for Employee

Comment: This question indeed has little to do with generics. This is more a question about inheritance and method selection.

Comment: How about introducing 2 interfaces like `Executive` and **`Staff`**, so that **`Developer`** implements **`Stuff`**, **`Director`** implements **`Executive`** and **`Manager`** implements both? In that case can make a method that accepts Stuff (effectively `Developer` and `Managers` are possible) OR another one accepting `Executive` (meaning you can pass either `Manager` or `Director`)

Comment: If you can edit and include a hypothetical example of what you are trying to achieve it would be quite helpful. Even if it does not compile